# MS ACCESS VBA Run-time error '3021'; with .MoveNext

Tags: vba, ms-access

this is my code

```
Dim Reloc, RelocPrev1, RelocPrev2 As String
Dim Blk, Blk2, Lt, Lt2, PrevDate As String
Dim LotComp, BlockComp As Integer


    Dim DB As Database
    Dim RS As Recordset

Private Sub SearchBtn_Click()

    Reloc = Me.RArea.Value

    Set DB = CurrentDb()
    Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset(Reloc, dbOpenDynaset)

    Blk = RS!Block
    Lt = RS!Lot
    Blk2 = Me.BlockTxt
    Lt2 = Me.LotTxt

    BlockComp = StrComp(Blk, Blk2, 1)
    LotComp = StrComp(Lt, Lt2, 1)

    RS.MoveFirst

    Do Until BlockComp = LotComp
        RS.MoveNext
    Loop

   Call RetrieveData

End Sub
```

RS!Block and RS!Lot works fine, only RS.Movenext and RS.Edit which I tried doesn't work.
My table is populated with more than 50 rows.
First item in the table can be pulled just fine, I just can't move to the next row with RS.MoveNext

Any ideas to make this work?

Comment: I've not used access for some time, but I wonder if you may be reaching the end of RS? ... Try adding `And Not RS.EOF`  to the loop condition so that it looks like: `Do Until BlockComp = LotComp And Not RS.EOF`. There is a nifty debugger built-in that is very useful. You can use that to step through the VBA code and inspect/print variables, if what I've mentioned does not help.

Comment: I tried putting a Msbox to show BlockComp and LotComp values, and it stays the same until the end and says no record found. Now I wonder why EOF doesn't work?

Comment: Provide sample data as a text table in question. As already suggested, step debug code. Why would you expect BlockComp or LotComp to change? Nothing inside loop would cause a change. What are you trying to accomplish? Not seeing RS.Edit in this procedure.

Comment: Blk2 and Lt2 is a user input. so I need to stop the loop when the user input and the data from table(Blk, Lt) is matched. Edit comes next, after I located the row and pulled the data

Comment: is there any way I can locate the rows like in excel? by x and y positions?

Comment: What is `RArea` about? Seems to be a sql, please provide it. All your variables but `RelocPrev2`, `PrevDate` and `BlockComp` are variants implicitely. You have to declare a type for each variable explicitely in VBA.

Comment: Yeah, RArea are the Table names. RelocPrev2 and PrevDate are not yet used, please ignore. BlockComp is an integer for comparing Blk and Blk2 if they matched. Cos I need to pull the record where Block and Lot is matched with user input.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. If you need to find a record that has data that matches variables or where two fields are equal, then need to reference recordset fields in the loop. `Do Until RS!Block = RS!Lot`. Or instead of looping records, use RS.FindFirst and RS.NoMatch. Or apply filter to form and display record there. How is Reloc set? Why not apply filter criteria to that SQL so only desired records are pulled. Do you expect only 1 record to retrieve?

Comment: `Do Until RS!Block = Blk2 And RS!Lot = Lt2`

Comment: Do you really even need to open a recordset? Maybe you just need to run an UPDATE action with user inputs. Why are users not entering data directly into record with a bound form?

Comment: I need to create a single dynamic form to control the tables thats why  need to open a recordset.

Comment: Sorry, that comment makes no sense to me.

Comment: Theres a lot of tables and only 1 form needed. How can I target other tables without opening a recordset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently expect only 1 record to match criteria. It would be best to apply filter criteria to recordset SQL so only desired records are pulled then test if recordset is empty.

To go to a single record that meets criteria, instead of looping recordset use FindFirst and NoMatch.

`RS.FindFirst "Block='" & Blk2 & "' AND Lot='" & Lt2 & "'"`
`If Not RS.NoMatch Then`

Comment: I'll try this FindFirst, hope it works. Thank you very much!!